# Post form and redirect to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I'm using this jQuery code to submit a dynamic form :

```
$('#formsite').on('submit', function (e) {
  //prevent the default submithandling
  e.preventDefault();
  //send the data of 'this' (the matched form) to yourURL
  $.post('inc/siteform.php', $(this).serialize());
});
```

but this method only sends the data to the PHP file. I want also that it redirects me to there, as an ordinary PHP POST submission.

How can I do it?

Here is the full testing site: http://edge-americas.com/control/main.html

UPDATE:

Using the method JQuery redirects me but it doesn't send the formdata at the same time so I can't use $_POST[] variables:

```
$('#formsite').on('submit', function (e) {
  //prevent the default submithandling
  e.preventDefault();
  //send the data of 'this' (the matched form) to yourURL
  $.post('inc/siteform.php', $(this).serialize(),function(response){
    window.location = "inc/siteform.php";
    });
});
```

Is there any other way to keep using jquery and solve it?

Comment: If you want to redirect user to the same page that should handle the form submition, then why do you use AJAX in the first place?

Comment: Because I've just started with JQuery and I don't know anything about AJAX or Javascript. Can you help me with the code? Thanks!

Comment: DO a simple POST request. You don't need to do it with AJAX.

Comment: I can't, this form adds some fields dynamically and the html doesn't recognize fields added after the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript works perfectly for this:

```
window.location.href = "URL";
```

Or as Andy pointed out if you want users to go back without issues simply drop the .

```
window.location = "URL";
```

Comment: window.location = "URL"; would be better as it allows users to go back in the browser with no issues. window.location.href can sometimes cause issues

Comment: But doing this it only redirects me to the php file and I can't use the $_POST[] data. I need to send the formdata at the same time I'm being redirecting.

How Can I do it? 

Thanks!

Comment: Dont use javascript, just submit the form using HTML

Comment: I can't, this form adds some fields dynamically and the html doesn't recognize fields added after the page loads.

Comment: Your form fields should still show up on the php file even if they are added using jQuery

Comment: When you submit the info using jQuery have it set a PHP session containing the $_POST[] and get the session after the user is redirected and use the info then.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `window.location.replace()` and pass in the URL of where you want to be redirected as a paramter.

[Location.replace()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_replace.asp) for more information on the method.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect or refresh page after succcess or server answer. For example:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"?show=ajax_request&action=add_offer",
    type:"POST",
    data: {var_to_send : somevar},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(answer){
        if ( answer.result == 'success' )
        {
            location.reload(); // refresh the page
        }
        else if ( answer.result == 'error' )
        {
            window.location.href = "http://google.com"; // redirect to another page
        }
   }
});
```